# Does using global objects in closures cause memory leaks?

Tags: javascript

```
var globalObject = {    
    prop1
    prop2
}
```

I have a global object, which i am referring inside my closures. Will this cause any memory leak.

```
(function(){
      var a;

      function inner1(arg){
        a = arg;
        globalObject .prop1 = dosomething;
      }

      function inner2(){
        globalObject .prop1 = add more properties to prop1
        globalObject .prop2 = dosomething;
        alert(a);
      }

    })();
```

After that i am calling my `inner2()` for a service call.

Comment: Please include the call to `inner2` in your code.

Comment: So `dosomething` are function expressions?

Comment: @Bergi: yes... they are function expressions.

Comment: @Bergi: inner function is just called from another file.... it does not include anything.

Comment: As your code stands, the inner function is not callable from outside. Would you mind posting your whole code?

Comment: frankly, your question is not clear. whether a memory leak will be caused is really depends on how you use these functions. here is a good reference http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning functions, which have access to the closure scope, to the global object. Therefore the variable environment of the closure call will not be garbage-collected until the functions are not longer accessible via the global object - which usually persists until your application is unloaded.

This will not necessarily be a memory leak. You seem to make the functions available via the global object for a good reason, and will expect them to work as long as they are accessible. For that time, the variables from inside the closure will *need* to be held in memory of course.